# Placing a new image in a new grid position

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-layout, tkinter-button

I have situation here where I want to press the button and add an image in. I have managed to get the first in perfectly but when I press the button to add the next one in it just stacks it on top. is there a way that I can move the position of a new entry every time I press the button to stop it stacking??

```
images = []
def add_friend():
    x = 0
    x += 1
    global friendImage
    friendFrame.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir= "/coursework - current/images/", title= "Select a friend",)
    friendImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(friendFrame.filename).resize((100,150), Image.NEAREST))
    friendImageInsert = Label(friendFrame, image=friendImage)
    friendImageInsert.grid(row= 0, column=x, sticky="NW")
    friendImageLabel = Label(friendFrame, text=friendFrame.filename.split("/")[-1])
    friendImageLabel.grid(row= 1, column=x)
    images.append(friendImageInsert)
    images.append(friendImageLabel)
```

so here is what it looks like right now:

[image]

If I was to open a new image and to place it in. How could I get it to place the next image in the column next to it in the same format? I want it to place it in a new column for every one that I add

Comment: What do you mean by "move"? Where should the new entry appear? What should it look like overall? Feel free to include (small) screenshots of the current results and/or diagrams/mock-ups of the desired results.

Comment: I have attached a screenshot and description of what I need

Comment: Aha. Did you try to check what the value of `x` is at the time that the `grid` methods are called? (Hint: at what time should `x = 0` happen? In particular, should it happen every time you add a new image?)

Comment: you should set `x = 0` outside function, not inside function - to create global variable. And inside function you should use `global x` to inform function that it has to use global variable when you do `x += 1`. And don't use `x = 0` inside function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to make `x` a global variable and initialize it outside the function.  Second you should not use same global variable `friendImage` for all images added because it will make the previously added image to be garbage collected.  Use an attribute of the label to store the image instead.  Also you can put the filename and the image together in a label instead of two labels.

```py
labels = []
x = 0
def add_friend():
    global x
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir="/coursework - current/images/", title="Select a friend")
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(filename).resize((100,150), Image.NEAREST))
    filename = os.path.basename(filename)
    friendImageLabel = Label(friendFrame, compound="top", image=image, text=filename, bd=1, relief='raised')
    friendImageLabel.grid(row=0, column=x, sticky="nsew")
    friendImageLabel.image = image # save a reference of image to avoid garbage collected
    labels.append(friendImageLabel)
    x += 1
```